# for loop stopping prematurely without covering all the items in the reference list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, calculated-columns

I am working on analyzing a housing dataset and it has temporal (year) features whose effect on the target variable (SalePrice) is what I am trying to visualize separately.

The way I am doing this is finding the delta of other year features and the YrSold feature to get "age" of house/remodeling/garage etc. and finally visualize how they affect the SalePrice

The problem is, if the new columns for the respective "ages" of the temporal features are not being calculated and created. Only one new feature column is being created as follows:

```
# creating a list of temporal features
temp_feature = [feat for feat in train_df if 'Yr' in feat or 'Year' in feat] 
temp_feature
```

Output:

```
['YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'GarageYrBlt', 'YrSold']
```

The loop:

```
vizdata = train_df.copy() # separating from main dataset

# looping through all
for x in temp_feature:
    if x != 'YrSold':
        vizdata[x+'new'] = vizdata['YrSold']-vizdata[x]
```

The output vizdata.head() shows only GarageYrBltnew at the end and not others, when it should add YrBltnew and YrRemodAddnew. I am guessing the problem has to do with how the loop is iterating through the list and the if condition.

Thank you

Comment: There is no reason to be using for loops here to start with. This should be vectorized

Comment: hi Noah, thank you. Could you please elaborate how vectorization can be applied here?

Answer (score 0):

this is not really an answer but does not fit into comments. Your code looks fine and should work. This works for me:

```
temp_feature = ['YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'GarageYrBlt', 'YrSold']
vizdata = pd.DataFrame(columns = temp_feature, data = [[1,2,3,4]])
for x in temp_feature:
    if x != 'YrSold':
        vizdata[x+'new'] = vizdata['YrSold']-vizdata[x] 
vizdata
```

produces

```
YearBuilt   YearRemodAdd    GarageYrBlt YrSold  YearBuiltnew    YearRemodAddnew GarageYrBltnew
0   1   2   3   4   3   2   1
```

*Which version of Pandas are you using*?

Comment: Interesting. My version is 1.0.5. What could be the versioning reason that such a simple loop is malfunctioning?

Comment: @Anish I don't know enough to comment, sorry. But updating to the latest seems like a fairly reliable way of solving such issues, although your version sounds recent enough. If you restart your python and run just the piece of code I have in my answer, what do you get?